# compare mutablearray results with original data to retrieve more content

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

After the user enters some text, the table view is filtered and results are on the screen.  I'm trying to get the rest of the data from my plist file which looks like this:

```
<dict>
<key>Things to do</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>activity</key>
        <string>Watch movies or TV shows</string>
        <key>keywords</key>
        <array>
            <string>tv shows</string>
            <string>movies</string>
        </array>
        <key>points</key>
        <string>10</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>activity</key>
        <string>Go Hiking</string>
        <key>keywords</key>
        <array>
            <string>hiking</string>
            <string>mountains</string>
        </array>
        <key>points</key>
        <string>50</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>activity</key>
        <string>Video Games</string>
        <key>keywords</key>
        <array>
            <string>video games</string>
            <string>playstation</string>
            <string>xbox</string>
            <string>nintendo</string>
        </array>
        <key>points</key>
        <string>5</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

Say the user enters "WAT" and the mutablearray searchResult contains "Watch movies or TV shows":

```
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[activityArray
  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

The initial data is loaded into an NSArray *tableData.  How do I search through tableData for matches and based on that match get the rest of the information?

```
if ([self.tableData containsObject:searchText]) {
   //or containsObject:self.searchResult still gives me a NO in the log
    NSLog(@"YES");
}else{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Or something like this...

```
for (int i=0; i< [self.searchResult count]; i++){
  if ([self.searchResult objectAtIndex:i] in self.tableData){
    NSLog(@"YES");
  }
}
```

Am I close?  How would I get the keywords values then?

Comment: Do you basically want to reload your table data when a search has been  made? If yes you would simply update tabledata with the new array you receive from DB

Comment: I want to insert the matched data into a new array...also would like to parse that array and, for example, insert "points" into the detailLabelText of the table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answers helps someone...after 2 days of scouring the web.  The searchResults is a MutableArray.  I needed to loop through both the MutableArray and all the NSDictionaries for every activity.  Then I inserted it into the table cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//basic initialization of table cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
//if there is something written in the search area...
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    //use i to loop through all tableData dictionaries
    //use j to loop through how many possible matches your search found
    int i=0; int j=indexPath.row;
    while (i < [self.tableData count]) {
    //get ALL the possible dictionaries and look through them for search matches
        NSDictionary *tempDic = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[tempDic valueForKey:@"activity"] isEqualToString:self.searchResults[j]]) {
            self.points = [tempDic valueForKey:@"points"];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellLabel = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"This activity is worth %@ points", self.points];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellLabel;
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row][@"activity"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"This activity is worth %@ points", self.tableData[indexPath.row][@"points"]];
}

return cell;
}
```

I tried adding explanations throughout the code, explanations I wish someone would have helped me with as I'm starting with objective-c.  Really hope this helps someone, if anyone needs more help with this I'll gladly assist.